# How to make circle thumbnail with GraphicsMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, image-manipulation, graphicsmagick

While exploring how to make circular crop with GraphicsMagick i came to that code:

`gm convert -thumbnail 200x200^ -extent 200x200 kira.jpg kira_new.jpg && gm convert  -size 200x200 xc:none -fill white -draw "circle 100,100 110,0" tmp.png && gm composite -compose CopyOpacity  tmp.png kira_new.jpg out.png`

Here's what it does:

1. Creates 200x200 temp file named kira_new.jpg
2. Creates transparent tmp.png with white circle in the middle
3. Composition on tmp.png and kira_new.jpg

So the question is: is there any way to make it shorter instead of running 3 commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

After *much* experimenting with GraphicsMagick, and disappointment at its lack of features and flexibility compared to ImageMagick (`-clone` where are you? `-swap` where are you? aside-processing where are you? `-alpha` where are you?), the nearest I can get to a single GraphicsMagick command without intermediate files is this:

```
{
   echo convert -size 400x400 xc:none -fill white -draw \"circle 100,100 200,100\" mpr:mask
   echo convert image.jpg -resize 400x400 mpr:image
   echo composite -compose copyopacity mpr:mask mpr:image result.png
} | gm batch -prompt off
```

**Original Answer**

Not sure how you would do that with GraphicsMagick, but as you have tagged with ImageMagick too, I will give a solution based on that:

Let's start with a red square as I don't have a *"kira"* to hand:

```
convert -size 400x400 xc:red image.jpg
```

[image]

Now, we clone the square (which is easier than getting its size and adding the dimensions) and then turn on its transparency. Then draw a circle, filled with whatever the default fill colour is - it doesn't matter so long as it is opaque. Then we tell ImageMagick it should copy the opacity channel when we composite in the next step before saving as a `PNG`:

```
convert image.jpg  \( +clone -alpha transparent -draw "circle 100,100 200,100" \) -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

If you want to do resizing, do it in the area where I have added dots:

```
convert image.jpg -resize ... -extent ... \( +clone -alpha ...
```