# Crop down to circle

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to crop a rectangular image down to a circle. I ran this command:

```
convert -crop 500x500+100+100 in.jpg out.jpg
```

However it creates a square rather than a circle.

Answer (score 4):

```sh
convert in.jpg -extent 400x400+100+100 \
  '(' +clone -alpha transparent -draw 'circle 200,200 200,0' ')' \
  -compose copyopacity -composite out.png
```

This *+100+100* part is optional: it allows you to shift the viewport.

[How to make circle thumbnail with GraphicsMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32274215)